# Package sqldf download error

Tags: sqldf, rstudio-server, rsqlite

I was trying to install the sqldf package in rstudio server by the code

```
install.packages("sqldf")
```

but when i tried downloading this the following error came

```
Installing package into ‘/home/mrshekar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/sqldf_0.4-11.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 63097 bytes (61 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 61 KB

* installing *source* package ‘sqldf’ ...
** package ‘sqldf’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** demo
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Warning: S3 method ‘format.SQLiteConnection’ was declared in NAMESPACE but not found
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RSQLite’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
 shared object ‘RSQLite.so’ not found
Error : package ‘RSQLite’ could not be loaded
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘sqldf’
* removing ‘/home/mrshekar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/sqldf’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘sqldf’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpJSQqsy/downloaded_packages’
```

Now as much as i understand there has been a problem with the RSQLite package but it has been downloaded separately and it aslo appears in my package tab. What is the error if i have done something wrong? Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Check your RSQLite package. It has been downloaded but it will also not work. Try deleting the package and then installing it again.

After that install the sqldf package again. This seems to work correctly for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not that. sqldf package installs the RSQLite package. Now i had installed it already and as you correctly pointed out about the error about the RSQLite package not being installed properly, even if i had just installed the sqldf package after deleting the RSQLite package then also it would have sufficed. No need to install the RSQLite package again. But thank you.

Comment: Oh okay. Well +1 for the clarification